Issue facing in auxiliary routing after updating to angular 17
I am using  auxiliary routing for a few of my components. After the angular upgrade to 17 it stopped working. I am opening the drawer using  auxiliary routing. What is happening is opening the drawer and then immediately closing that. For example, my route is localhost:4200/ABC/(drawer: popup). when i open the drawer (drawer: popup) are added to the URL and then removed immediately. so the popup opens and then closes automatically. And this happens when I run an application with a container. without container like i run my application as a simple angular application its working fine. Let me know if you have any solution for this issue.
I tried updating "single-spa": "^6.0.1","single-spa-angular": "^9.1.2" but nothing happen. Drawer should open on calling routing
